# Variável estática em Python

Tags: python, django

Vim do Java. Tenho uma variável numa classe que preciso mudar em mais de um método.

Tentei colocá-la global, mas consome muito recurso.

1. Como implementar isso?
2. Seria a mesma forma que uma variável estática em Java?
3. Como modificar `var` de outra classe no Django?

   ```
   var = 0
   def metodo1():  
   var += 1      
   def metodo2():  
   var += 10
   ```

[**Resolvida**]

Obrigado pela resposta do colega abaixo. Resolvi da seguinte forma:
Criei uma classe 'estática':

```
class Modulo(object):
    andamento_processo = 0
    def processo(self):
        self.andamento_processo = 1
```

Agora eu instancio ela da outra classe e altero o valor quando precisar, é literalmente como se fosse uma variável estática (do java)!

```
class NovaClasse:
    Modulo.andamento_processo = 10
```

Comment: Cuidado com varíaveis criadas no corpo de classes em Python: são atributos da _classe_ e não atributos das instancias, como em Java. O exemplo acima e da resposta funcionam, mas funcionariam sem as variáveis de classe - recomendo deixa-las de fora se não forem exatamente o que você quer. (E não, uma variável "global" em Python é apenas um atributo do objeto módulo, não é algo tão "terrível" como uma variável global em C. Ter uma classe só para ter um atributo que você pode modificar pode ser uma prática ruim em Python. Ou pode ser uma boa no caso de vários grupos de variáveis no mesmo módulo

Answer (score 3):

A Orientação a Objeto no Python é um pouco diferente. Se você cria uma variável ela por padrão fica acessível. A diferença é a seguinte: Se a variável for acessada por uma instância do objeto, ela é atributo do objeto, caso contrário ela é atributo da classe.

Exemplo:

```
class A(object):
   variavel = 1
```

Dessa forma é de objeto:

```
objeto = A()
objeto.variavel
```

Dessa outra forma já seria um artificio bem parecido com o do Java (como você quer):

```
A.variavel
```

Para tentar deixar mais claro, imagina que sua classe tem um inicializador que muda o valor da variável de 1 para 5. Quando chamar o primeiro código que mostrei vai ser retornado 5, se o segundo código for chamado, vai retornar 1.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

class A(object):
  variavel = 10

  def __init__(self):
    self.variavel = 15


print A.variavel #resultado 10
print A().variavel #resultado 15
```

Fonte para mais informações:
[Static variables and methods in Python](http://linuxwell.com/2011/07/21/static-variables-and-methods-in-python/)