# É possível criar uma propriedade estática em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, static, decorator-pattern

Eu preciso criar uma classe que possua um atributo de nome, porém este deve ser estático e imutável, ou seja, um `static final` em outras linguagens de programação. Em Python, existe o conceito de properties, logo, eu pensei em criar uma property estática, apenas *getter*.

```
class MyClass:
    
    @staticmethod
    @property
    def name():
        return "Nome da classe"
```

Porém o decorador `@property` necessita que o método tenha um `self`. É possível fazer isso em Python?

Comment: Relacionada: [Variável estática em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13225/vari%c3%a1vel-est%c3%a1tica-em-python)

Comment: O problema não é só a variável ser estática. Isso daí eu já conheço. Eu preciso que ela seja estática e final. Além disso, ela deve ser acessada não só a partir da classe, mas também a partir de qualquer objeto. Ou seja: `MyClass.name == objeto.name`.

Comment: Final que diz é que não pode ser alterada?

Comment: Exatamente! ....